# Receiving data from remote server

Tags: c++, http, sockets, proxy, remote-server

I am having problems receiving data from a remote server. It seems that I can send an HTTP request to a host such as http://www.google.com, but I can't get a reply.
I'm sending the host a HTTP 1.0 request that is formatted as such:

GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.google.com
Connection: close

Here are is part of the proxy code:

```
    //Parse Request Buffer
    HttpRequest req;
    req.ParseRequest(request.c_str(), request.length());

    //Format Data to be Sent:
    req.AddHeader ("Connection", "close");  // add connection close headers
    req.SetVersion ("1.0");                 // set http 1.0 flag
    char *requestBuf = new char [req.GetTotalLength()];
    req.FormatRequest(requestBuf);

    //Get host IP by name
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname(req.GetHost().c_str());

    //Setup remote address structure
    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr;
    remoteAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
    remoteAddr.sin_port = htons(req.GetPort());   
    remoteAddr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);

    //create new socket for remote server
    int remoteSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(remoteSock < 0)
    {
            perror("Socket Error");
            //return -1;
    }

    //connecting to remote server
    if(connect(remoteSock, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddr, sizeof(remoteAddr)) < 0)
    {
            perror("Connect Error");
            //return -1;
    }

    cout.flush() << requestBuf << endl;
    //send request to remote server
    if(send(remoteSock, requestBuf, sizeof(requestBuf), 0) < 0)
    {
            perror("Write Error");
            //return -1;
    }

    //receive reply from server
    char *recBuf = new char [1024];
    int bufSize = 1024;
    int readSize;

    while(1)
    {
            readSize = read(remoteSock, recBuf, bufSize);   //Read from Remote Server
            cout.flush() << recBuf << endl;
            if(readSize <= 0)       //If the requestBuf not filled, nothing left to send to client
                    break;
            write(clientSock, recBuf, readSize);            //write reply to Client

    }

    close(remoteSock);
```

The cout.flush() of recBuf outputs nothing.
Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: (1) You need to check for read error (`if(readsize <= 0)`) BEFORE you write the result, not AFTER. (2) Please show the code that sets up `requestBuf`. In particular, the use of `sizeof(requestBuf)` looks very suspicious, because the request is not likely the occupy the entire buffer. (3) The `recBuf` is not NUL-terminated, so you must not treat it as such, as you do in your `cout.flush() << recBuf << endl;` line.

Comment: I included suggestion (1). Some more code about how requestBuf is set up is added (It is difficult to show how requestBuf is completely set up there is an entire API given to me for it)

Comment: To not treat recBuf it as NUL-terminated, can I just add a \0 to it?

Comment: Technically, no, because it might have NULs embedded within it. Use the length you got back from `read`, just like you do in the `write` system call. For example, `fwrite(recBuf, 1, readSize, stdout)` (that's a C-ctyle stdio operation, not C++, but you can use it anyway).

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
if(send(remoteSock, requestBuf, sizeof(requestBuf), 0) < 0)
```

you are only sending (probably) 4 or 8 bytes to the remote end. `requestBuf` is declared as `char *`, which is a pointer type. Instead of `sizeof(requestBuf)`, you need to pass the actual length of the request you have built, which seems to be `req.GetTotalLength()` in your case.